# Design Patterns/Database schema for workflow

Tags: java, design-patterns, database-design, workflow

May I know what are the design patterns for work flow?

The workflow needs to be dynamic and loaded from database and allow forward and backward change of status.

So far I earmark the following design pattern

Design Pattern

State, chain of command, command.

Database design

??

My friend recommend me camel and jbpm but will it be an over kill?

Your inputs will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If its simple status transition based workflow with DB persistence, take a look at OSWorklfow (JIRA uses this)..

Comment: hmm if we are using some API, the client will request for a more complete business solution like jbmp.